# How can I insert a None/Null value for a int column?

Tags: python, fastapi, asyncpg

I'm using fast API and I have an optional input. In the event it's not provided, I just do not want to insert anything, here's my class:

```
class NetZeroAddGoalsRequest(BaseRequest):
    target: int
    description: str
    target_date: Optional[str] = "1/1/2050"
    update_frequency_month: Optional[int] = None
```

then I update it into my db:

```
company, target, description, target_date, update_frequency_month = body.company.upper(), body.target, body.description, body.target_date, body.update_frequency_month

# insert into DB
res = await main_db_instance.fetch_rows(f"INSERT INTO company.transition_company (company_name, target_carbon, description, target_date, update_frequency_month)"
                                        f" VALUES ('{company}', '{target}', '{description}', '{target_date}', '{update_frequency_month}')"
                                        f" RETURNING *")
```

but I am getting this error:

```
invalid input syntax for type integer: "None"
```

my DB column type is int, and I've tried to set the class variable to "" but then I get an error that I'm passing a string.

How do I have an optional int in fast API?

edit: if it helps, I'm using asyncpg - I tried to isolate it and it seems to be with the insert statement. If I comment it out then I do not get the error.

Comment: Can your database column accept null values, did you maybe accidentally set it to not nullable?

Comment: @elano7 Thank you - I did check and the int column can accept null values.

Comment: @Lostsoul does my answer works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use some ORM, like [SQLalchemy ORM](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/) or even something that helps us remove boilerplate with fastapi/sql models ([tortoise](https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is great here!) with them you could do something as simple as

```
session.add(MyModel(**body.dict()))
```

But if you just want to make your example working, convert **None** to **null**, as db is not aware of **Nones**

```
update_frequency_month = 'null' if update_frequency_month is None else update_frequency_month
```

And do not use '' in sql statement

Answer (score 1):

> my DB column type is int, and I've tried to set the class variable to
> "" but then I get an error that I'm passing a string.

`None` (Python type, not a postgres/SQL type) is not int, `""` is not int. If you are using asyncpg it should convert the value automatically to `null` from `None`. I suspect that is because you insert the values directly into the SQL using a formatted string.

Try using native query argument syntax:

```
('''
    INSERT INTO company.transition_company (company_name, target_carbon..)
        VALUES ($1, $2,..) 
 ''', company, target,..)
```